# Error Number:134,State:1,Class:15

Tags: c#, sql

I'm generating data in a console app and inserting them in a database.

I can currently generate one row and it's inserted in the database without any problem.

EDIT: I added the piece of code I'm currently trying to use in a while loop.
EDIT 2:Problem solved using Parameter.Clear as stated on a comment below.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: "which means that a variable is already declared", please post what you are doing so we understand how you get to this error

Comment: I've added the code I'm trying to loop on, if you remove the while loop, it works just fine but only inserts one row in the database which is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code above, I'm assuming your command is not disposed of since you are manually disposing of the connection.  So the garbage collector has not cleaned the command up.  So the parameter variables are declared.  If you modify your command like the following:

```
public void Insert()
{
     using(var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
     using(var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
     {
          connection.Open();
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("", "");
          command.Params.Add("", SqlDbType.Int, "");
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
}
```

Then you would create your loop that you desire, pass whatever parameters you want to method which I left empty for brevity.  Should work without an issue.

You could also simply do `Parameters.Clear()` then read them, to ensure the command parameters aren't populated already.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but `AddWithValue` has [significant problems](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and you should not be telling beginners to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added the code that I'm trying to run and it seems like it's the same as yours.

Comment: @Greg Thanks for the answer, I just wanted to thank you a lot , I add'ed CMD.Parameters.Clear(); and now everything works like a charm !

Comment: @DourHighArch I usually don't use `AddWithValue`, basically I prefer to explicitly state the database type.  However, I do feel that in most basic implementations it will suffice.  Ultimately, that would be up to the developer and the code.  But that'll be a lesson they encounter in their developmental growth.  I added a manual parameter add, so they can see both and choose their preferred way.